# How to get battery icon to match percentage?

Tags: gnome, icons, battery, icon-themes

I have added the "show battery percentage" feature within the gnome tweak tool menu, but my battery icon does not mirror this and my OCD is getting the best of me.

Is there a way to change the battery icon settings to match the actual charge percentage instead of it always looking fully charged?

[image]

**Specs:**

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Kernel: 4.13.0-38-generic

DE: Gnome 3.18.5

WM Theme: Adwaita

Theme: Numix [GTK2/3]

Icons: Numix-Circle [GTK2/3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for my experience with the Battery indicator it's not possible (ubuntu 17.10), but i found a nice tool in the Software center which is called Circular Battery Indicator, which matches it pretty good, though it looks something different.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this alternative. I'm still partial to the traditional battery indicator, but if no one else chimes in with another solution, then the answer karma is yours!